# How to validate multi-checkbox state?

Tags: php, jquery, xhtml

I am using [position absolute's validation engine](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) for my form. I would like to check whether at least one checkbox from group is selected. In [examples](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoCheckBox.html) it is done by setting the same `name` attribute for group of checkboxes.
I cannot name checkboxes with the same name, because I am saving their state in database with following code:

```
$values = array(
    'checkbox1'         => null,
    'checkbox2'         => null
);

foreach (array_intersect_key($_POST, $values) as $key => $value) {
    $values[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

$query_add_candidate=sprintf("INSERT INTO dbase (checkbox1, checkbox2)    VALUES    ('$values[checkbox1]', '$dates[checkbox2]')"
```

Now `checkbox1` and `checkbox2` are validated individually, beacuse they have different names. How can I check if selected is at least one of them?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="maxcheck1" value="1"/> Text1
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="maxcheck2" value="2"/> Text2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on php ,

```
if(!$_POST['checkbox1'] && !$_POST['checkbox2']){
    echo 'Error check at least one';
}
```

but what you really want is an array, 
HTML,

```
<input type="checkbox" value="ch1" name="check[]" /> 
<input type="checkbox" value="ch2" name="check[]" />
```

php

```
<?php 
if(empty($_POST['check'])){
 echo 'Error: hey, check at least one will you!?'; 
}

?>
```

so this way you don't have to check all of them one by one, especially if you have loads of them on the same page.

**NOTICE**: You should also know, if checkbox is not ticked it will also not be set on the php $_POST superglobal, otherwise if it is ticked, it will show whatever the `value="..."` holds,

Comment: Okay then, I have three checkboxes and I want to save their state to database: 
    `$date1 = isset($_POST["date"][0]) ? $_POST["date"][0] : 0;
    $date2 = isset($_POST["date"][1]) ? $_POST["date"][1] : 0;
    $date3 = isset($_POST["date"][2]) ? $_POST["date"][2] : 0;` But [here is how it works](http://i.imgur.com/RecYS.jpg) - on the left are checkboxes statuses, on the right there is array content.

Comment: I don't understand your question here, what check and save meant to represent? also you will lose the prefix Zeros (leading) because if they are saved as integers, which is numbers, the zero adds no value, so you may have to save them as strings.

Answer (score 1):

if its posted then its checked,

so if you have it in `$_POST["checkbox_name"]` then its checked, otherwise it wont be posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add loads of code to reimplement control arrays in a poor way, or you can alter the code that builds your query so it can accept control arrays.

I would prefer the latter.